# fillna not working together with column conditions in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, null, nan, data-cleaning

I am trying to fill NaN values in a dataframe column, but only if a condition in another column is met (I'm working with Kaggle Titanic data). For example:

> ```
>       Age    Title
> 0     10       Mr
> 1     2        Master
> 2     NaN      Master
> 3     NaN      Mr
> ```

In this table, I want to replace the NaN in the 'Age' column with a number, but only if the value in the 'Title' column is 'Master', not if it is 'Mr'. So I want to replace the row 2 NaN, not the row 3 NaN.

I'm trying this and don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[df['Title'].str.contains('Master'),'Age'].fillna(some_number,inplace=True)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, should have mentioned that. I don't get an error, it just does nothing and the NaN values do not get replaced.

Comment: OK, so this works:    df.loc[(df['Title'].str.contains('Master'))&(df['Age'].isnull()),'Age']=some_number.  But I still don't get why my original code does not work.